# Designing a Page for Screen and Print Medias - Font-Size

Tags: css, printing, font-size

I've created a report which is shown on the screen and it should be printable as well. The application has to support IE 6.0 too.

What font-sizes should I be using?

I've read, I should be using em for Screen media (web page) and pt for print media (I know em is scalable and pt isn't...).

How would you design such a page in terms of the css elements?

e.g. creating a separate css file for print media and duplicating all your css classes there and just modifying the font-size? so much duplication.

Isn't there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to duplicate that much.

Create your report for the Web.

Then, in the body of your stylesheet add a reference for print styles, like so

```
@media print {
div#content {background:#fff; width:90%; font-family:serif; font-size:12px;}
div#header, div#insideheader, div#topnav, div#footer, 
div#navcontainer, p.pic img {display:none;}
div#main {border:none; background:none;}
a {color:black;}
}
```

In the example above, I am

1. setting the `background-color` to `white` and extending the content to fill the `width` of most of the page
2. removing most of the extra pieces, like the `nav` and `footer`, extra pics, etc.
3. changing the link colors
4. setting the font to a `serif font`, easier to read for print, and a size of `12px`, which is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the first style sheet is marked media all, and the second style sheet is media print, the second style sheet will effectively be an extension, and over-rider of the first for print media.  Prefer points for print and ems for screen.

Have a look at this article for other things you might not have thought about.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: Thanks, em is somewhat difficult to work with; all elements inherit from the font-size of each other; needs a proper design. I added a background-color: Red to a div element inside my print stylesheet but it doesn't show the red background when printed, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Your browser settings can be configured to allow the printing or background images or colors, or not.  Google will help you find directions to modify your own browser settings, but unfortunately you can't control what settings your users will use.

Comment: For help working with ems, check out technique 1 of http://trevordavis.net/blog/the-6-most-important-css-techniques-you-need-to-know